# this.props.history.push is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, push, history

I am creating a form with some predefined values, and i want to route to the dashboard page once the form is submitted. I am using handleLoginSubmit func on the onsubmit of the form. For that, I have the following code:

```
handleLoginSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let hardcodedCred = {
  email: "email@email.com",
  password: "password123",
};

if (
  this.state.email == hardcodedCred.email &&
  this.state.password == hardcodedCred.password
) {
  //combination is good. Log them in.
  //this token can be anything. You can use random.org to generate a random string;
  // const token = "123456abcdef";
  // sessionStorage.setItem("auth-token", token);
  //go to www.website.com/todo
  // history.push("/dashboard");
  this.props.history.push("/dashboard");

  // console.log(this.state.route);
  console.log(this.context);
  console.log("logged in");

  // <Link to={location} />;
} else {
  //bad combination
  alert("wrong email or password combination");
}


};
```

But, I am receiving the error saying that history is undefined.
Please help me out here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to export the component with router to access history

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export default withRouter(ComponentName)
```

Answer (score 5):

if your component is linked with `Route` then you can directly access that in `this.props` but if its sub-component or children of some component then you cant access it into `this.props`.

so there is multiple way to solve it

1. pass history as props in your component if that component is linked with `Route`

```
<Component history={this.props.history} />
```

2. use `withRouter` HOC, that bind all `Route` props in your component

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export default withRouter(Component)
```

3. use `useHistory` hook and save it to constant ( functional component )

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const history = useHistory();
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update of [Nisharg Shah's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65448108/10117433) answers of part 3 for future reference.

If you are using **react-router-dom v6**, then [use useNavigate instead of useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory).

You can use:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

let navigate = useNavigate();
```

OR

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  function handleClick() {
    navigate("/home");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>go home</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i resolved this issue